# Detect Completion of Retriving Data with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `observeSingleEventOfType` for `.Value` and `observeEventType` for `.ChildAdded`. As `.ChildAdded` retrieves existing data (not only just added), I need to trigger `.ChildAdded` continuous observer after `.Value` is completed. But as `.Value` is behaving like a for loop (goes through the block several times) I couldn't sort it out with a boolean variable.

```
var initialLoad = true   

myRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
  // Retrieve Stuff from Database

  // when completed
  initialLoad = false

  print("A")
}

myRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
  if initialLoad == false {
      // Observe only for newly added events
      print("B")
  }
}
```

The print log looks like this (B gets intervened)

```
"A"
"A"
"B"
"A"
```

I tried this approach but there is a second which `.ChildAdded`'s part run on initialLoad. I guess it's because it behaves like a for loop. I want run `.Value` on initial load and `.ChildAdded` just to observe changes.

What is the best of way achieving this?

Comment: I have trouble understanding your goal. Are you trying to find only children that are added after your program starts?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, With `.Value`, I am trying to fetch everything previously added. And after that, with `.ChildAdded`, I want to observe the newly added items. Isn't that the right way of doing it? I want `.ChildAdded` to start working after `.Value` is completed retrieving data.

Comment: Yes, that's a common practice (although it would be a lot better if you include a timestamp in a property and use a `startAt` to filter on that). Your `observeSingleEventOfType(.Value` will only fire once. Unless something is suddenly really broken in our SDK, the other `"A"` prints have to come from somewhere else.